# How to create MYSQL FULLTEXT index for very large table?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a table in MYSQL database that is about 45GB and my disk available space is 30GB. The table type is MyISAM and MySQL version is 5.6. I want to create FULLTEXT on two columns of the table called name and text where  name is varchar(255) and text is longtext.

Will MYSQL create temporary table of about the same size as the size of the table ( 45GB) when creating index?

Which is better to use:

ALTER TABLE ADD FULLTEXT or CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX in above context?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html

Answer (score 2):

The two commands are the same (one maps to the other).  It will make a full copy of the table with all its new indexes.  So, it is impossible since you have less free disk space than even the table size.

Get bigger machine?  Remove other stuff?  Do other cleanup?

Note further, the FT index may be close to 45GB, itself.  So, even if you could create the index, it might overflow your 30GB.

InnoDB's `FULLTEXT` seems to create a much smaller index.  But still, converting to InnoDB cannot be done without *more than* 45GB free space.

Comment: If this is the case then the only other option is to buy 64GB USB thumb drive and attach to my macbook. But then the question how can I tell MYSQL to use external thumb drive for making copy of the database?

Comment: This won't be the last situation to deal with.  You really should worry about disk space before worrying about that index.

Comment: If you are thinking of dumping the entire database (not just this table), any external drive (such as that thumb drive) can be mounted and used as a file system to write to.